# is it possible to route mails from qmail to postfix

Tags: qmail

My server IPs are getting blacklisted because of some spamming activity. In order to save it from getting it blacklisted I am planning to route all the mails from unknown ids to be routed through postfix(postfix have the sender blocking functionailty and hold queue which qmail does not have)

These are mostly the qmail-remote related mails(outgoing mails) so possibly a hack in qmail-remote to call the postfix.

Any ideas/suggestions are heartily welcomed.

Comment: This sounds to me like it would fit better on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching of mail from qmail queue to postfix is not possible because of permissions issue. We can have a hack in qmail-remote to route the mail in case the sender is blacklisted. Its a normal smtp protocol code that need to be implemented in order to push the mail to postfix. qmail-remote already does it while sending the mails to other domains. Postfix can be made to run on non-standard ports (in order to avoid possible hacking) for mail acceptance.